# How to properly type elements and event targets in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, dom

In TypeScript why can I do this:

```
const element: HTMLInputElement = document.querySelector('input');
```

but I cannot do this:

```
const element: HTMLInputElement = event.target;
```

As I understand it, `HTMLInputElement` is subtype of `Element` returned from `document.querySelector`.

But in the second case, `HTMLInputeElement` is also a subtype of `EventTarget` so why the first line works and the second one gives me a type error?

**EDIT**: I have strict null checks disabled thus I do not need to deal with nulls here.

Comment: I take it you have strict null checks disabled? (It's somewhat tangential, but your first assignment would be invalid if they were enabled because the target doesn't have `| null`.)

Comment: Very interesting question BTW.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, indeed. I edited the question for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In TypeScript why can I do this....but I cannot do this...

Because `querySelector` is an overloaded generic function, but `Event["target"]` just has a simple type. You can't assign a supertype (like `EventTarget` or `Element`) to a subtype (like `HTMLInputElement`) without narrowing (or an assertion). What's happening instead is that the return type of `querySelector` is fairly sophisticated and making it so that you aren't actually doing that.

In your *specific* case with the literal string `"input"` as the argument, you can do it because `querySelector` has this signature that applies:

```
querySelector<K extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap>(selectors: K): HTMLElementTagNameMap[K] | null;
```

That lets it map the string literal argument `"input"` to `HTMLInputElement`. (This also means you don't need the type annotation, the type of `element` [would be inferred](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgGzgWzmKBGGBeGATEYAV1XQDoBHIuAJwE8BlROYKEGgCgCIBLMAByJQuASgDcAKAD0UmHJgA9APwSgA) as `HTMLInputElement | null` even if you didn't have it, thanks to that overload.)

In contrast, `Event["target"]` is simply:

```
readonly target: EventTarget | null;
```

Nothing fancy going on there, so if you want to treat it as an instance of a subtype, you have to either use a type assertion or a predicate.

---

The more interesting case (to me) is:

```
function example(selector: string) {
    const element1 = document.querySelector(selector);
    //    ^? const element1: Element | null

    const element2: HTMLInputElement | null = document.querySelector(selector);
    //    ^? const element2: HTMLInputElement | null
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwB4EMC2AHANsgCgGdl9o4AnALkSKgpjAHMBKRAbwChEfEIE6KfJmRgoARkQBeRABM4EECLEA6AI4hkFAJ4BlUsnIViBoywDc3XgHprvRAD0A-Jys9+YQQeVQATDQAJABUAWQAZAEkwbBAoAFFhUShEAB9EMBBcXGk5BSUk9U0dfTIoShNSygs3RFt7Z04AX04gA)

In that case, the overload I quoted above doesn't apply, because the argument is just a string, not a string literal, and could have any selector at all in it. This is the overload that applies:

```
querySelector<E extends Element = Element>(selectors: string): E | null;
```

For `element1`, since we aren't providing the type argument and TypeScript has nothing to use to infer it, it defaults to `Element`, so the call returns `Element | null`.

For `element2`, though, why does it allow it? Why can we assign `Element | null` to `HTMLInputElement | null` even though we haven't used a type assertion or predicate (or explicit type argument)? **We aren't.** Instead, TypeScript is inferring the type argument from `element2`'s type.

Let's see it do that ‐

`element1`:

[image: TypeScript playground showing that for element1 the call is querySelector<Element>(selectors: string): Element | null]

`element2`:

[image: TypeScript playground showing that for element2 the call is querySelector<HTMLInputElement>(selectors: string): HTMLInputElement | null]

Notice the difference in the inferred type argument, and thus to the return type. Because of the inferred type argument, the result is `HTMLINputElement | null`, so the assignment is valid.

---

*(For my various examples, I have all strict checks enabled, but just read past the `null`s.)*

Comment: Thank you, now I understand even more than I asked.